# Different Author Comment in Blogger - Cannot Detect CSS .icon.blog-author

Tags: html, css, blogger

I'm trying to make different style for author comment in my blogspot : [Teknomia](https://teknomia.blogspot.com/)

I'm using stock comment (default from blogger)

I use this code :

```
#comments .comments-content .icon.blog-author:after{
  content: 'Admin';
  background-color: #118ff9; 
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

But, Blogger can't detect this code, which identify tag for author :

```
.icon.blog-author:after
```

When I try to change my code like this :

```
#comments .comments-content .user a:after{
  content: 'Admin';
  background-color: #118ff9; 
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

It work (all comment include my visitors comment marked as author)

I want to know how to marked author comment only (only my comment marked)

Comment: Your first code is working properly on my blog when I tested. So my guess is that you have some conflit with other style... or the span blog-author not present or hidden... Can you share a link to your blog?

Comment: Ok. I visited your blog and your first code is working. The only thing I see is that you have 2 accounts named Teknomia but only one of them is assigned as owner/author of the blog. If you want both to show the author comments, probably you will have to grant the same access to both accounts...